The max_connections in PieCloudDB 2.12
I would like to know how to view the value of the max_connections parameter on each instance of the current computing cluster on PieCloudDB database version 2.12? In addition, if I want to modify this parameter, what should I do?

You can use the following command to view max_connections:
select * from gp_toolkit.gp_param_setting('max_connections');

If you want to modify this value, first, you need to log in to the operation and maintenance platform.
you can execute this command on the PiecloudDB cluster to access.
kubectl get svc -A|grep istio-ingressgateway-ops

and then enter the user name and password, find the data warehouse ID of your cluster in the data warehouse management interface, and after entering, you can modify the GUC as needed.
